# ng-click only where paper-input form is valid

Tags: angularjs, polymer

I'm new to web and can't figure this one out:

I have a form that I want the submit button to be disabled while the form is invalid.
I've tried using the X.$valid and the X.checkValidity() but with no help. I've also looked at the iron-form examples and documentation but I can't

I assume my trouble is the use of Angular + Polymer but I can't find a solution to how to get the behavior I want.

here is my code:

```html
<form id="loginForm" novalidate>
  <paper-input ng-model="username" label="{{::tr('Enter a username')}}" required auto-validate error-message="{{::tr('Please enter your username')}}" ng-keyup="keyPress($event.keyCode)" ng-change="password = ''"></paper-input>
  <paper-input ng-model="password" label="{{::tr('Enter a password')}}" required auto-validate error-message="{{::tr('Please enter your password')}}" type="password" ng-keyup="keyPress($event.keyCode)"></paper-input>
  <div id="loginFailureReason"></div>
  <div class="pm4-form-footer">
    <paper-button raised ng-click="forgotPassword();" ng-enable="!loading">{{::tr('Forgot your password') }}</paper-button>
    <paper-button raised type="submit" ng-click="loginForm.$valid && login()" ng-enable="loginForm.$valid && !loading">{{::tr('Sign in')}}</paper-button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Code of the controller:

```
loginApp.controller('LoginController', ["$scope", "$http", "$window","trFilter",
function ($scope, $http, $window, tr) {
    //Used to determine if to present the reset password form or not
    $scope.resettingPassword = false;
    //Used to determine if to present the reset code form or not
    $scope.submitResetCode = false;

    //Model fields that will be sent to server
    $scope.username = '';
    $scope.password = '';

    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;
        $('input[ng-model], select[ng-model]').each(function () {
            angular.element(this).controller('ngModel').$setViewValue($(this).val());
        });
        $http.post('/Account/DoLogin', { username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password }).
            success(function (data, status, headers) {
                if (headers('AccountCtrResponse') !== null && headers('AccountCtrResponse') === "Done") {
                    $window.location.replace("/" + $window.location.hash);
                } else {
                    $scope.logonFailureReason = tr("Login failed due to the following reason: " +headers('AccountCtrResponse'));
                    $scope.loading = false;
                }
            }).
            error(function () {
                $scope.logonFailureReason = "Failure in submitting the request. Try again later or report this if it persists.";
                $scope.loading = false;
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I add the following code it works but I think it is incorrect to put that logic in the controller. In the html:

```
<paper-button id="submitionButton" raised type="submit" ng-disabled="!formValidity()">
    {{::tr('Sign in')}}
</paper-button>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.formValidity = function () {
    return loginForm.checkValidity();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    <form name="loginForm" >
        <paper-input ng-model="username" label="{{::tr('Enter a username')}}" required auto-validate error-message="{{::tr('Please enter your username')}}" ng-keyup="keyPress($event.keyCode)" ng-change="password = ''"></paper-input>

        <paper-input ng-model="password" label="{{::tr('Enter a password')}}" required auto-validate error-message="{{::tr('Please enter your password')}}" type="password" ng-keyup="keyPress($event.keyCode)"></paper-input>
        <div id="loginFailureReason"></div>

        <div class="pm4-form-footer">
            <paper-button raised ng-click="forgotPassword();" ng-disabled="loading">{{::tr('Forgot your password') }}</paper-button>
            <paper-button raised type="submit" ng-click="login()" ng-disabled="!loginForm.checkValidity()">{{::tr('Sign in')}}</paper-button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: I get for the $valid or $invalid an "undefined". When I try this 'ng-disabled="!loginForm.checkValidity()"' then the button is disabled but doesnt turn enabled when I fill the form (even though that running the checkValidity() at that point in the console results with True)

Comment: can you share the controller code too. I am not sure of whats going wrong.

Comment: $valid: True if all of the containing forms and controls are valid.
$invalid: True if at least one containing control or form is invalid.

you no need to write
ng-click="loginForm.$valid && login()"

try writing 
ng-click="login()" ng-disable="loginForm.$invalid && loading"

Comment: Tried ng-disable="loginForm.$invalid" and it doesn't do anything. not sure why but the $valid/$invalid are undefined. if I do ng-disabled="!loginForm.checkValidity()" then the button is disabled when page loads but when I change inputs to pass validation the button stays disabled (even though the checkValidity() returns true

Comment: You have taken id as loginForm, instead you take 

<form name="loginForm"></form> and remove novalidate.

you can use "loginForm.checkValidity()", hope you have included jQuery in your project.
(or).
 you can work around using  [AngularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

loginForm.$valid or $invalid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114007/discussion-between-dinesh-sundaraneedi-and-gilad-green).